# Can't delete offending photo in Group chat as administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-groups, facebook-photos

I am an admin/owner of a Messenger Group Chat (GC). A member posted a gross photo and everyone wanted me to remove it, but I couldn't. Before, admins can directly remove it for everyone.